# How to fix "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf-protection

I am following a tutorial about a shoppingcart.Its from 2016. And i cant run the CSRF protection in my Index.js because of the error it gives me

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');
var csrf = require('csurf');
router.use(csrfProtection);
var csrfProtection = csrf();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
...
.
.
...
});
router.get('/user/signup',function(req, res, next){
  res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

module.exports = router;

C:\Users\Jelson\Desktop\Shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:451
    throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Jelson\Desktop\Shoppingcart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:451:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jelson\Desktop\Shoppingcart\shopping-cart\routes\index.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: You're using `csrfProtection` instance before declaring it.

Comment: @Mandalina  actually this is my Index.js code and it has only 25 lines. If you request the code from the express\lib\router\index.js then its 
if (callbacks.length === 0) {
    throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function')
  }

Comment: @sigfried well it seemed to be the error. now it worked after i changed the 2 lines Thx..

Comment: @JelsonF.Matthew you're welcome mate. Happy hacking ;)